# how to change the color of materialToolbar in CollapsingToolbarLayout?

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design

This is my layout

```
<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/coll_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize">

            </com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar>

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
```

If this layout isn't the first activity/fragment,  the toolbar wolud have a back icon .

But the color of **back icon** is black.

I want it to be a whit color.

I search it in github,but nothing.

And I found the demo in google shown, they use the code `android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"`to the `CollapsingToolbarLayout`.Then the color of back icon will be the white.

I want to know what happen?

I trace back to the code `android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"`.I find
it's parent is `Base.ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar`

Just this :`<style name="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" parent="Base.ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>`

And then I trace back to the code `Base.ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar`.I find
it haven't parent,and it implement the code

```
<item name="colorControlNormal">?android:attr/textColorPrimary</item>
        
<item name="searchViewStyle">@style/Widget.AppCompat.SearchView.ActionBar</item>
```

Just this :

```
 <style name="Base.ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
    <item name="colorControlNormal">?android:attr/textColorPrimary</item>
    <item name="searchViewStyle">@style/Widget.AppCompat.SearchView.ActionBar</item>
</style>
```

So I think the key is `colorControlNormal`.

So I create a new style,and use it with
`<item name="colorControlNormal">..my Color..</item>`.But I am wrong.

So I want to know what should I make the color of back icon to be white by change one or several attribute instead of use `android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"` .

Answer (score 0):

You are using MaterialToolbar widget from the Material Component library.
You can specify the back arrow color using `app:navigationIconTint`.
Here's the documentation https://material.io/components/app-bars-top/android#using-top-app-bars.

Comment: Oh,no only the color of back icon.I also want to change the color of content in Toolbar...

Comment: Maybe there are some ways  by one/two line code that can finish my need.

Comment: Do you mean the background color of the toolbar? You can try applying the color using `android:background` to AppBarLayout and MaterialToolbar.

Comment: No the background. I mean like the color of icon,the color of textview...